# Migrating from amazon SimpleDB to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, azure, web, amazon-simpledb

I've got an interesting problem. I recently started working at a new company that's using Amazon SimpleDB and amazon S3 to do all their storage. Having large domains is killing their performance. Instead of splitting up domains, they want to go to an SQL solution (Microsoft azure). What would be the easiest way of migrating to this?

Keep in mind, The datatypes from Amazon's SimpleDB are being used internally in the program, so simply exporting each domain's data as string to an sql table would be ok to start with.

That being said, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: OK, got this working. For anyone else trying to get this done, use simple db explorer, export all of your domains to CSV (Leave the settings alone!). Import the data into a local MS SQL database using the data importer (Right click database > import), select flat file, and select the CSV file (Change the .txt filter in the bottom right to csv). In the import options, make sure you set it so that the first column is the column title. Also make sure each column has enough characters (SimpleDB Stores everything as char), and import. If you get truncation errors, increase the char field size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a web based tool called [BackupSDB](http://backupsdb.com/) that claims to backup SimpleDB domains to XML files and then store them on S3.  You should be able to download the XML and then import it into SQL with your preferred ETL tool...

I've never tried BackupSDB personally, so this is purely theoretical... :-)

Comment: That might save me some time. Currently I'm using simple database explorer to export a CSV file, and manipulating the data by hand to get it into the database properly. Thanks for the quick reply, I'll let you know if it works well.

Comment: This application would have worked, but I used the method I updated the OP with. Marked as correct answer because it works.